# Boot from Windows Setup files that are located on a partition

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, grub, uefi

Here's the situation:

I am on a Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 13 (1st gen). I do not have Windows installed on my computer, I have Ubuntu. I currently use Grub2 and/or refind to boot Ubuntu. I would like to install Windows, and I am in possession of the Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 isos. I would make an install usb but: 1. previous attempts have failed (even used Microsoft's official tool) 2. I do not currently have a usb large enough to hold the contents of either iso.

Attempted Solution: Use raw disk feature of VirtualBox to boot iso and install onto physical disk (worked for Ubuntu), but UEFI support for VirtualBox is inadequate, without which Windows setup cannot detect disks. Using an XP setup can only see the protective MBR, installing upon which would wipe whole disk.

Proposed Solution, with no method of implementation: Would it be maybe possible to extract the contents of the setup iso onto a GPT partition on the drive (NTFS/FAT/EFI I don't know), and then boot into setup from Grub or refind? How might I go about this?

If you have any other better proposed solutions that might work given my limitations, please do share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes, installing Windows from a disk partition to another disk partition should work. The partition in question should use FAT so that it can be booted. You'd need to copy the files from the Windows disc onto the partition, and ensure that it has an `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` boot file. If you copy your Windows 8 disc and find that it lacks this file, try this:

1. Using any available computer, copy all the files from the UDF side of your Windows installation disc to the partition. (A Windows 7 installation disc has both ISO-9660 and UDF filesystems on it, and I'm assuming that Windows 8 is the same way. Thus, you may need to adjust mount options to access the UDF side. The ISO-9660 side holds only a text file stating that you need to have UDF support to access the disc.)
2. Extract the `1/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi` file from the `SOURCES/install.wim` file on the Windows installation disc. This file is in Windows Imaging Format, which you can extract with 7zip. (I used 7z under Linux.)
3. Place the `bootmgfw.efi` file on the target partition, under the `EFI/BOOT` directory (which you may need to create).

Comment: I'm working on this.. will update as I get through it.

Comment: Only thing is.. it works, it boots into setup, but it cannot see any of the hard disks on my comp, which are just normal Samsung SSDs. Still marking answer correct.

Comment: That sounds like a driver issue. Check with your computer manufacturer for Windows drivers. I don't recall the precise details, but I know there's a way to load a driver in the Windows installer. You'll need to put the driver file(s) on a USB flash drive or CD-R or something.